# Powershell Invoke-Command with file share

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script like this:

```
param([string]$zipFileLocation)
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($zipFileLocation))
{
 write-host "No location provided" 
 return $false
}

write-host "Location of zip: $zipFileLocation" 
write-host "Test-path result: $(test-path($zipFileLocation))"
write-host "END OF SCRIPT"
```

When I run this script locally, with as argument '\Server\Share', Test-Path returns true and all works fine. I.e. when I run `'.\TestScript.ps1 -zipFileLocation '\\Server\Share'` it works as expected.

However, if I run the command like this:

```
$remsession1 = New-PSSession -credential $credential -ComputerName $ServerName
$UnzipPackageResult= Invoke-Command -session $remsession1 -FilePath C:\Test\TestScript.ps1 -ArgumentList '\\Server\Share'
```

Then the 'test-path' in the script comes back with `$false` and an `UnauthorizedAccessException` error. I do not see why.

The provided credentials do have administrator rights on the server.
Any thoughts?

Comment: _"The provided credentials do have administrator rights on the server"_. Do they also have appropriate permissions for `\\Server\Share`? Have you tried to manually log into $serverName using these credentials and do a `Test-path \\Server\Share`?

Comment: @Zett42, yes if I manually log into $serverName and run "TestScript1.ps1"  on that machine, with the credentials provided, I have no issues.